# how to convert 3d matrix to 2d matrix ? rearrange data to 2d

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, reshape, netcdf4

the shape data is (288,63,79)
which the first is (time,lat,long)

how I want to rearrange the data the row is the lat & long
and the column is time?

I don't know how to reshape to 2d with the shape (288,63,79)

thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you should convert the matrix (288, 63, 76) into (63 * 76, 288)?
Then, you can write the below code.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array(data)
x = np.reshape(data, [data.shape[0], -1])
x = np.transpose(x)
```

You can change the shape of matrix by `np.reshape`, It should convert the matrix (288, 63, 76) into (288, 63*76).

Then you can use `np.transpose` to swap the dimension of the matrix.